# Is it possible to separate this function into product of function of A and B?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Is it possible to convert the following function

$$-\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$$

into

$$f(A) \times f(B)?$$

Comment: Not too sure about a product, but a difference definitely. Reference the product-to-sum formulas [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Trig_Cheat_Sheet.pdf). Based on the form that'd result, I can't imagine the result would be easy to change into a product...

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I have edited the question. Its A-B in both sin and cos, so that link doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The way you have written it, implies that it should be the *same* function in the product. Is that intended?

Comment: @DavidPeterson    Yes, it should be the same function but A and B separated.

Comment: A double-angle formula implies that the expression is equal to $-\sin(A-B)$, which is simpler but not yet a product of the form you want. And sine is odd, so this is $\sin(B-A)$.

Comment: Can you add some context as to why you want such a strict form? I'm having trouble proving it's impossible, and can find some other forms that might be nicer for some calculation application.

Comment: @MarkS., this is not a difficult proof, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, even if you write it as a product of two distinct functions. If it is possible to write it in that fashion, then it is also possible to write $-2$ times this in this way.
$$\sin(A-B) = f(A)\times g(B)$$
$$\implies f(A)g(B)+f(B)g(A)=0\forall A,B\in\Bbb R$$
$$\implies \dfrac{f(A)}{g(A)}+\dfrac{f(B)}{g(B)}=0\forall A,B\in \Bbb R$$
If we define $h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, whenever $g(x)\ne 0$, then
$$h(x)=-h(y)$$
whenever both sides are defined. This is not possible, because
$$h(x) = -h(y)\hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm}h(y) = -h(z)$$
$$\implies h(x) = h(z)$$
But $$h(x) = -h(z)$$
we get a contradiction.

Comment: May I know the reason, dear downvoter, so that I can put a better answer next time??

Comment: Downvoted by mistake, now can't undo it as its locked, please make a small edit

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  your answer addresses only sin(A-B) when taken alone, but when taken along with cos(A-B) as binomial function, does this proof hold good??

Comment: @VARUN.NRAO, $-2$ times the quantity you want to write is actually $\sin(A-B)$, by the double angle formula. If  we can write your quantity as a product of two functions, then we can also write $\sin(A-B)$ as a product of two functions, by multiplying one of the functions by $-2$. Therefore, it holds good.